# Выполнение одной хранимой процедуры N-количество раз с разными параметрами

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, хранимые-процедуры

Для вставки огромных массивов сущностей (допустим, от 100к) есть расширение для EF - BulkCopyAsync. Данное расширение позволяет вставить в таблицу огромное количество записей в очень короткий промежуток времени. Но при попытке найти что-либо похожее на тему хранимых процедур поставило меня в ступор. Теперь к проблеме.

Репозиторий:

```
public async Task<List<Person>> GetMatches(Person[] persons)
{
var personMatches = new List<Person>();

var templateStoredProc = "EXEC pMatches @FamilyName, @FirstName, @Patronymic, @BirthDate, @Result OUT"; // Выражение хранимой процедуры с параметрами

foreach (var person in persons)
{
    SqlParameter resultParam = new()
    {
        ParameterName = "@Result",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    };

    var fullName = person.PersonInfo.FullName;

    var sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>()
    {
        new SqlParameter("@FamilyName", fullName.LastName),
        new SqlParameter("@FirstName", fullName.FirstName),
        new SqlParameter("@Patronymic", fullName.MiddleName),
        new SqlParameter("@BirthDate", DateTime.Parse(fullName.BirthDate)),
        resultParam
    };

    await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(templateStoredProc, sqlParams);

    if ((int)resultParam.Value > 0)
        personMatches.Add(person);
}

return personMatches;
}
```

Хранимая процедура:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pMatches

     @FamilyName  varchar(100) = null 
    ,@FirstName   varchar(100) = null 
    ,@Patronymic  varchar(100) = null 
    ,@DateBirth   date = null 

    ,@Result      int = null output
```

Собственно сама проблема заключается в том, что, нужно обработать каждый элемент входящего массива на наличие записей в таблице, соответственно в цикле обрабатывается каждый элемент, и на выполнение каждой хранимой процедуры уходит порядка 80мс. А во входящем массиве может быть и по 10к элементов, и на обработку уходит безумно много времени

UPD:
Рассматривал как вариант объединить все запросы в один SQL запрос, но как получить список со всеми этими найденными совпадениями?

Comment: Запустить несколько Taks'ов, чтобы обрабатывалось всё не одним потоком? Только учтите, что нужно будет несколько экземпляров DbContext'a, в этом поможет IDbContextFactory

Comment: @OwDafuq как возможный вариант, да. Но хотелось бы найти решение лаконичней

Comment: К сожалению я думаю, что другого и не будет, т.к. DbContext не позволит выполнить 2 параллельных запроса за раз, например. К слову у меня так в проекте текущем и сделано, как я написал выше

Comment: На счет вашего UPD: попробуйте сделать табличную функцию/х.п. (что не есть хорошо, конечно), которая вернет таблицу, а не просто Int, где будет 1 столбец - id найденной записи и его вернете к себе в клиентский код, а дальше уже обрабатывайте таблицу

Comment: @OwDafuq если бы была такая возможность. Данный сервис не должен иметь прямого доступа к каким-либо данным из этой таблицы, только на поиск совпадений

Comment: В этом и есть смысл, что вернется ваша кастомная таблица, содержащая ТОЛЬКО id'ы совпадений и ничего больше

Comment: @OwDafuq благодарю за наводку, попробую реализовать. Но думаю в конечном итоге оставлю все как есть, так как сервис работает по расписанию в фоновом режиме, и кроме как во время отладки не напрягает его долгая обработка

Comment: Передавать/возвращать Table Valued parameters. Делать это одним запросом.

Comment: @Valeriy Ну, в любом случае он не должен такие простые операции делать N минут, вообще, судя по коду, делов на несколько секунд, "не напрягает" - это сейчас, а дальше начнет напрягать, придется переделывать, имхо

Comment: Я немного поискал, находится множество примеров, как передавать table-valued parameter, в том числе в EF. Но сходу не нашёл примера возврата, но по сути то же самое. Думаю, справитесь.

Comment: А индексы в таблице есть? Хотя бы по дате рождения, мне кажется уже хорошо должно записи разделять. И вообще если одна и та же процедура часто дёргается, она должна кешироваться `SQL` сервером, да и таблица, к которой она обращается, тоже, так что по идее оно само должно хорошо масштабироваться, странно если нет.